# Excel2011 VBA Trimming String with invisible characters for PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, texttrimming, vba

I'm a new member of your community, my name is Thomas.

I used to be a Visual FoxPro developer years ago, but for now I'm trying to learn how to handle Excel (2011 on a Mac) and VBA. Only in my spare time ;-).

I have googled a lot since I started and really often found the answer right here, so here I come.

Here is the (almost) whole picture: I'm retrieving data from HTML files (Bridge competition results), at some point (row) there's fixed column data and one column contains 2 Player's names separated by `" - "`.

I have no problem to retrieve the first one but can't trim the second one.

I have tried `TRIM`, `CLEAN`, `SUBSTITUTE` with all CHAR -> 31 and CHAR 127, 129, 141, 143, 144 and 157.

I even try this, found somewhere on google :

```
Sub Clean_and_Trim_Cells()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim s As String
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        s = c.Value
        If Trim(Application.Clean(s)) <> s Then
            s = Trim(Application.Clean(s))
            c.Value = s
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

So, for the same player, I end up with different length of string one who is properly trimmed and another one longer. That I don't Understand.

And here is how I define the length of the columns and extract names:

```
Sub PieceOfCode

    If Left(Trim(cDataString), 4) = "Rang" Then      ‘Header row
            
        'Here we define the columns width and initiate data collection
        nScore = 0
        cTeamName = ""
        cTeam = ""
        cP1 = ""
        cP2 = ""
        nCol1 = InStr(cDataString, "Rang")
        nCol2 = InStr(cDataString, "Paire")
        nCol3 = InStr(cDataString, "Score")
        nCol4 = InStr(cDataString, "Nom")
        nCol5 = InStr(cDataString, "Equipe")
        nCol1Length = nCol2 - 1
        nCol2Length = nCol3 - nCol2
        nCol3Length = nCol4 - nCol3
        nCol4Length = nCol5 - nCol4
        nCol5Length = Len(cDataString) - nCol5 + 1
            
        'And further in the process...
                                             
        nScore = Val(Mid(Replace(cDataString, ",", "."), nCol3, nCol3Length))
        cNamesString = Mid(cDataString, nCol4, nCol5 - nCol4)
        nSplitTeamNamesPos = InStr(cNamesString, " - ")
        cP1 = Trim(Mid(cNamesString, 1, nSplitTeamNamesPos - 1))
        cP2 = Trim(Mid(cNamesString, nSplitTeamNamesPos + 3))
                    
    End If
            
End Sub
```

When I build a PivotTable with this I get 2 entries for the same player.

Here the code I have to create the pivot table, I confess, with the help of the recorder, but even if that's why, I'd know how to trim my string.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

    Dim nRowCount As Integer
    Dim cRowCount As String

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    nRowCount = GetRowCount("Data")
    cRowCount = Trim(CStr(nRowCount))

    Range("A1:B" & cRowCount).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Data!R1C1:R" & cRowCount & "C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="TempPvt!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable8", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Sheets("TempPvt").Select

    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Nom")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("Score"), "Total", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("Score"), "Sum of Score2", xlSum
    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable8"",""Sum of Score2"",""# Tours"",,4)"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("Score"), "Sum of Score2", xlSum
    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable8"",""Sum of Score2"",""Moyenne"",,8)"

End Sub
```

And finally here is two strings with header for testing (BAPTISTE Claude is the target).

```
Rang  Paire  Score  Nom                                                       Equipe          
     
        302   1,83  Mme NIMSGERN Monique - BAPTISTE Claude                    Mme EMERIQUE    


Rang  Paire  Score  Nom                                                  Equipe          
     
   8    101   0,92  BAPTISTE Claude - Mme NIMSGERN Monique               Mme EMERIQUE
```

That's it.

Comment: VBA's Trim only works on leading and trailing null characters. If there are any within the string, you need worksheetfunction.trim

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer but this doesn't solve my problem. The 4th column is 53 chars long and I still can't get rid of what's left after the last letter of the second name. I'll find another way but this is troubling me.

Comment: Once you get the `cNamesString` you could use `Split(cNamesString, " - ")` then trim both items